# Merge vertices along an edge

Tags: mesh, vertices

After using a loop cut for the first ring, i copy pasted it with shift+d along the Z axis. How do i "paste" the vertices on the edge? (As if they were all loop cut and connected with the column)
I Had auto merge vertices on for the whole project, but it never seems to work.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you've chosen the good method, you can't merge a separate edge or vertex with the middle of a face. What you can do though, if you're glad with a segment of your cylinder, is duplicate, move it on Z and snap it to the previous segment with the *Snap to Vertex* and *Auto Merge* options activated, or give your segment an *Array* modifier on the Z axis:

[image]

Another way is to create some loop cuts (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>) and bevel (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>):

[image]